# Where can I find System.Windows.Controls.dll and System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll

Tags: wpf

I'm using WPF, VS2010 and VS2008

Are these libraries available with Silverlight only?
Is PresentationFramework.dll == System.Windows.Controls.dll?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for the System.Windows.Controls namespace (not the .dll). The namespace you refer to is indeed in PresentationFramework.dll that is part of the Windows SDK from Microsoft (afaik not a standard part of the .Net framework).

System.Windows.Controls.Data is in the System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll assembly file.

The System.Windows.Controls.Data namespace is part of Silverlight, which most recent sourcefiles you can download at: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=D09B6ECF-9A45-4D99-B752-2A330A937BC4&displaylang=en

Both assemblies reside on my pc in "Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0"

Edit: wrong Silverlight download link. Corrected :)

It is possible that the Controls.Data dll is not in the recent SilverLight SDK, so if nothing else helps you can find it in an separate download: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=084A1BB2-0078-4009-94EE-E659C6409DB0&displaylang=en

Comment: You are right! I've added reference to PresentationFramework, but can't find the 2nd one - System.Windows.Controls.Data.dll.
Sorry, I'm newbie in WPF.

Comment: Both links don't work. a recent link to SilverLight SDK 4: https://www.microsoft.com/en-eg/download/details.aspx?id=7335

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, I found the path when I right clicked on the Toolbox in design mode and clicked Choose items... then on Silverlight components tab

I found it in PROGRAM FILES (x86)\MICROSOFT SDKs\SILVERLIGHT\v5.0\LIBRARIES\CLIENT. Click on file and then click add.
 What I did was Click on Project on the file menu then add Reference clicked on Browse (bottom of screen) and enter the above path. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error with a WPF project (rather than a Silverlight project)

It was caused by me not having the (quite old) WPFToolkit.dll installed on my new laptop.

https://wpf.codeplex.com/