# How to use rating control in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I appologise if it's stupid question. There should be some rating control in WPF at leas they say it [here](http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1959-rating-control-wpf-toolkit.aspx).

First I should add assembly `System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit`. Then I should be able to use it.
I don't know how to reference it in my project. When I choose "add reference" I cannot find it there. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839620/where-can-i-find-system-windows-controls-dll-and-system-windows-controls-data-dll) question they say it can be found in "Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\PresentationFramework.dll" but when I add this .dll as a reference I still cannot use it.

Thank you for answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535), which you can find on CodePlex.

Comment: It looks like my problem was that I have old version of WPF Toolkit - from 2009. So there was no rating control... I hope that this is the problem...