# System.Windows.Controls Assembly Reference Not Found VSCODE

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, reference, .net-assembly

I've been trying to work on programming at school, so I got vscode on my chromebook. However, when trying to write a c# script with the Canvas class, the Windows.System.Controls assembly reference is not found. I've tried looking around, but I can't find anything that tells me what to add to my .csproj, and I can't find the Solution Explorer on vscode, so I haven't found a way to add the reference. Anything will help, I have access to the Debian terminal, and all projects in vscode.

[update] I add the PresentationFramework Package Reference, but I still cannot access the System.Windows.Controls namespace.

Comment: see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1839620/where-can-i-find-system-windows-controls-dll-and-system-windows-controls-data-dl

Comment: @meysamasadi but can i even get silverlight on a chromebook? I thought it was a windows only application